# How to get didSelectRowAt IndexPath to differentiate between sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a set up that transfers info (the index for the cell selected) in a tableViewController so that the destination UIViewController can display some text info on a label by calling the appropriate index from an array. This all works correctly. However, there are 3 sections and I want the destination UIViewController to know which section was selected. (Ie. selecting the first cell in section 1 and the first cell in section 2 both return an index of 0, but I need it to be differentiable). I thought of passing the value of the selected section (and then setting up an if/else statement in the destination UIViewController) but I am not sure how to do that appropriately. 
Here is the current code I have for the non-differentiating index pass:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let rowSelectedd = indexPath?.row
        let destViewController: Controller = segue.destination as! Controller
        destViewController.rowSelected = rowSelectedd! 
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "rowSelected", sender: rowSelectedd)
    }
```

Basically, how do I pass the value of the section of the selected cell?

Comment: What is `rowSelectedd` inside the `didSelectRowAt` method? That won't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the destination controller needs both the row and section of the selected row, then use an `IndexPath` property instead of an `Int` property and pass the whole `indexPath` instead of just `indexPath.row`.

But why does the destination controller need to know the index path? That makes no sense. Why not pass the actual data for that index path (from your data model) to the destination controller?

Comment: that is because the data in that cell comes from an iteration from a bunch of arrays (all from the same index). I just want to display them on a larger page so I figured I would just iterate through the same array with that indexpath.row value. How would I transfer the data instead?

Comment: 1) Your data should not be in a bunch of arrays. It should be in one array. 2) To pass the data instead of the index path, make a property for the data instead of the row or index path.

Comment: Are you referring to a multidimensional array? Because my data comes form query pulls out of a DB and different properties of the queried object are appended to different arrays. Don't know how I would do that without a bunch of arrays, unless you mean a multidimensional one?

Comment: You should have a class (or struct) that represents one object with properties for each value. Then have an array of those objects.